# Finding the most(multiple) common word in C++ using unordered_map approach

Tags: c++, debugging, unordered-map

Find the most common word from a text input, excluding a list of given words. If there are multiple maximum words, display all of them.

My method words for 21/24 test cases, I cannot seem to think of the 3 test cases that I am missing.

I am adding the code that I have right now, which is efficient according to me. I don't want another way of implementing it right now (although suggestions are most welcome), I would just like to pick your brain about the possible test cases I am missing.

```
 vector<string> mostCommonWord(string paragraph, vector<string>& banned) {
        unordered_map<string, int>m;


       for(int i = 0; i < paragraph.size();){
            string s = "";
            while(i < paragraph.size() && isalpha(paragraph[i])) s.push_back(tolower(paragraph[i++]));  // go through till you find one word completely
            while(i < paragraph.size() && !isalpha(paragraph[i])) i++; // avoid all the white spaces and other characters
            m[s]++; // include the word found and increment its count
        }
        for(auto x: banned) m[x] = 0; // make the count of all the banned words to be 0

        vector<string> result;
        string res = "";
        int count = INT_MIN;
        // find the maximum count
        for(auto x: m)
            if(x.second > count) count = x.second;
        // we might have the case where all the words were in banned words, which would result the count == -1, so return an empty vector in this case
        if(count <= 0) return result;
        // add the words corresponding to that to the final vector<string>
        for(auto x: m)
            if(x.second == count) result.push_back(x.first);
        return result;  
    }
```

It works for all the scenarios I can think, but fails 3 test cases.
I am not given access to those test cases, would just like to have a discussion of what it could possibly be!

Comment: `for (const auto& x: banned) m.erase(x);` seems better, handles paragraph with only banned words.

Answer (score 1):

1. Are you sure in the fact that other chars (digits) should be treated as word delimiters?
2. If `paragraph` starts with a whitespace or not an alphabetical char you will insert the empty string into the map: `m[""] = 1`.

Comment: That is actually a very good observation! Thanks.
Any other scenarios you can think of?
And yeah, only english alphabets are considered as words!